# Class in python 3.9.4 gives inconsistent attribute error when calling method

Tags: python-3.x, methods, attributeerror

In Python 3.9.4, I have build a class `ForagerAgent` containing many methods. With the relevant code referring to information sharing between two different ForagerAgent objects. an example of the relevant code:

```
class ForagerAgent:
    
    def __init__(self):
        heatmap = {}

    def receive_heatmap_knowledge(self, shared_data):
        
        received_alternative_indices = shared_data[0]
        received_alternative_data = shared_data[1]

        received_counter = 0
        while received_counter < len(received_alternative_indices):
            # add knowledge if the alternative is unknown
            received_index = received_alternative_indices[received_counter]
            received_data = received_alternative_data[received_counter]
            if isinstance(self.knowledge[received_index], int):
                self.knowledge[received_index] = received_data
            received_counter += 1
```

If I access this manually from a test case object this yields the expected result:

```
from src.agents import ForagerAgent

forager_A = ForagerAgent()
forager_A.heatmap = {'stock_1': 100.0, 'stock_2': 0}
forager_A.update_list_of_knowns()

forager_B = ForagerAgent()
forager_B.heatmap = {'stock_1': 0, 'stock_2': 15}

data = forager_A.share_heatmap_knowledge() # method that yields knowledge as (['stock_1'], [100.0])
forager_B.receive_heatmap_knowledge(data)
print(forager_B.heatmap)
```

results in `{'stock_1': 100.0, 'stock_2': 15}` as one would expect.

However when calling this method inside another objects method, e.g.:

```
class DataSharer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def share_knowledge(self, forager_a, forager_b):
        data = forager_a.share_heatmap_knowledge()
        forager_b.receive_heatmap_knowledge(data)


forager_a = ForagerAgent()
forager_a.heatmap = {'stock_1': 100.0, 'stock_2': 0}

forager_b = ForagerAgent()
forager_b.heatmap = {'stock_1': 0, 'stock_2': 15}

data_sharer = DataSharer()
data_sharer.share_knowledge(forager_a=forager_a, forager_b=forager_b)
```

It is highly inconsistent in Errors and proper functioning. In some other class objects (like the `DataSharer` example above)_it will work just fine, while in others it will yield an `AttributeError: 'ForagerAgent' object has no attribute 'receive_heatmap_knowlegde'`

Does anyone know of any common (human) mistakes or bugs in Python 3.9.4 that may cause such an inconsistency in `AttributeError`? and how one might be able to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, a common human mistake is to type `knowlegde` instead of `knowledge`.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem.